# Can I use jquery to make anchor links automatically toggle a toggle menu on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu, toggle

I used jquery to make a toggle menu where someone can click on different span titles to toggle between different containers of content (on the website, this toggle menu toggles between different contact forms). The menu works, but I am trying to make it so that if a user clicks an anchor link on a different page, they will be sent to this page and the menu will automatically toggle to the corresponding container of content.

For example, if someone were to click on an anchor link like "mydomain.com/test-page/#third", I would want the content from the third menu item to toggle and show automatically when the page loads. I have been playing around with using "window.location.hash" to trigger a click event like this, but can't figure it out.

Is there a way to trigger a click event when the page url has a certain anchor hash like this at the end of it?

Would really appreciate any help folks can offer!

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecv5jwsr/

Code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <!-- the toggler -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
        <p id="toggle">
            <span><a href="#" id="test">TITLE 1</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" id="test">TITLE 2</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" id="test">TITLE 3</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" id="test">TITLE 4</a></span>
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
</div><!--container -->
<div class="container p-5 contact-page-forms">
<div class="row pl-md-5 pr-md-5">
    <div class="col-12 pt-4">
        <div id="left">
            <h3>Content 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <h3>Content 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="third">
            <h3>Content 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="four">
            <h3>Content 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#toggle > span').click(function() {
        var ix = $(this).index();

        $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
        $('#second').toggle( ix === 1 );
        $('#third').toggle( ix === 2 );
        $('#four').toggle( ix === 3 );

    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent("#test").click();

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to read the `#third` fragment from the URL in the next page, not the current one

Comment: to clarify, this is the page users would land on, I am basically hoping to link to this page in such a way that the toggle menu automatically opens to whatever anchor menu item they click on on another page.